# Session lifetime

Tags: php, session

I face a problem with session lifetime on my local web-server and remote one. On my local web-server session die only when I close my browser, but on remote It die every 24 minutes, I suppose(first  session.gc_maxliftime was =1440, I change it to 0, but nothing has changed). The php.ini configs are equal on both machines.

I need session on remote web-server die as on my local (only when I exit my browser)

Where I can find any solution?

Comment: What about [session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime)? Is it 0?

Comment: Have you tried turning the server off and on again?

Comment: "Have you tried turning the server off and on again? " - Yes, of course.
session.cookie_lifetime set to 0 too

Comment: There may be other scripts running that use the same [session.save_path](http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) with a lower [session.gc_maxliftime](http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime).

Comment: By the way, with [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)=0 a session becomes invalid immediately. And you spelled session.gc_maxlifEtime wrong -- maybe there's your problem ;)

Comment: No, setting session.gc_maxlifetime to 0 means the session will not expire until the browser is closed.

I think the problem is in the garbage collector and session.save_path

Comment: No, poku, that is not the case. [session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) is what you are referring to. [session.gc_maxlifetime=0](http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) means the session will be considered 'garbage' after 0 seconds. Look it up in the manual.

Comment: Look at this post [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php#82149)

Comment: That comment at php.net is wrong. If you don't believe me try it yourself: Set [session.gc_maxlifetime=0](http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime), [session.gc_probability=1](http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability), [session.gc_divisor=1](http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor). Your session variables won't last two requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the whole chain:

1. .htaccess
2. httpd.conf (...and includes)
3. php.ini
4. browser config (incl. proxy, trusted sites)
   -> if you get timeout or other errors, which are not server but browser generated

Good starting points are the phpinfo() and the apache log files.

Short explanation on 4: Often locally hosted websites are trusted in browsers, while server sites end up in the internet zone, which is protected. 'Protected' means, that all sort of presettings including timeouts differ from the ones for trusted sites.

Comment: Thanks, I've already solve this problem. I was wrong in php.ini file, server used another one)